# Can I get AirPlay mirroring under Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, airplay

I have a big TV hooked up to a Windows desktop via HDMI. I can launch VLC fullscreen and pretend I'm watching TV, or run BBC iPlayer, and that works fine.

I also have iPads and iPhones, and a MacBook. I'm aware its possible to start a server process under Linux to accept AirPlay mirroring from iPhones etc. (I saw a video demonstrating it on a raspberry pi).

**However, is this possible using Windows?** Or will I be forced to dualboot Linux/buy Apple TV?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming related question.

Comment: Then where should I ask it?

Comment: Ah Super User, could somebody please move it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a paid application called Aerodrom which is supposed to do this. I've briefly tried the free demo and it worked fine for photos, but the one video I tried crashed it. Unfortunately the free demo doesn't do audio only (which they claim the paid version will do). I'm primarily looking for an audio solution, and after my experience with video in the demo I'm reluctant to shell out 10 euros to learn if audio actually works.

Perhaps someone else has a more detailed experience with it? Anyway, you can find it here:

http://funky-factory.blogspot.com/p/versionsinfo.html

Comment: shame its a paid for app but it works

Comment: "shame it's a paid for app" -- There is no such thing as a free lunch.

Comment: There is, and if I were under Ubuntu I would have free lunch every day, but I'm not

Answer (score 2):

AirServer is now available for Windows. AirServer is also the first and only software that can Mirror your iPhone/iPad to your Windows PC. A 7 day trial version is also available from their website:

http://www.airserverapp.com/Download